# How to show or load Main Form (MDIParent1) after RunWorkerCompleted in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdiparent

I have a many Splash Form, MDIParent Form and others form. My Scenario process like this: Project Statup - SPlash Form, After Splash Form show first time and check some files, etc and after checking will be show MDIParent1 and splash form will close automatically.

This below is my code inside Splash form:

```
Public Class frmSplash
Dim m_CountTo As Integer = 0 ' How many time to loop.
Private Sub My_BgWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles My_BgWorker.DoWork

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_CountTo
        ' Has the background worker be told to stop?
        If My_BgWorker.CancellationPending Then
            ' Set Cancel to True
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) ' Sleep for 1 Second
        ' Report The progress of the Background Worker.
        My_BgWorker.ReportProgress(CInt((i / m_CountTo) * 100))
        SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblPercent, FormatPercent(i / m_CountTo, 2))

        If i = 10 Then
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblMessages, "Initializing..")

        ElseIf i = 40 Then
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblMessages, "Checking Mysql Service..")
        ElseIf i = 50 Then
            If CheckIfServiceIsRunning("MySql") = False Then
                ' Is the Background Worker do some work?
                If My_BgWorker.IsBusy Then
                    'If it supports cancellation, Cancel It
                    If My_BgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
                        ' Tell the Background Worker to stop working.
                        My_BgWorker.CancelAsync()
                    End If
                End If

                SetButton_ThreadSafe(Me.btnExit, True)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf i = 70 Then
            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblMessages, "Checking Internet Connection..")
        ElseIf i = 80 Then
            If CheckURL("http://www.google.com") = False Then
                SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblMessages, "No Internet Connection..")
            End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub My_BgWorker_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles My_BgWorker.ProgressChanged
    ' Update the progress bar
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
Private Sub My_BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles My_BgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        Me.lblMessages.Text = "Cancelled"
    Else
        Me.lblMessages.Text = "Completed"
        My_BgWorker.CancelAsync()
        Me.Close()
        MDIParent1.Show()

    End If
End Sub
Delegate Sub SetLabelText_Delegate(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)

' The delegates subroutine.
Private Sub SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(ByVal [Label] As Label, ByVal [text] As String)
    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    If [Label].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New SetLabelText_Delegate(AddressOf SetLabelText_ThreadSafe)
        Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[Label], [text]})
    Else
        [Label].Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
Delegate Sub SetButton_Delegate(ByVal [Button] As Button, ByVal [visible] As Boolean)

' The delegates subroutine.
Private Sub SetButton_ThreadSafe(ByVal [Button] As Button, ByVal [visible] As Boolean)
    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    If [Button].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New SetButton_Delegate(AddressOf SetButton_ThreadSafe)
        Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {[Button], [visible]})
    Else
        [Button].Visible = [visible]
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub frmSplash_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Set the count to 100
    m_CountTo = 100
    ' Start the Background Worker working
    My_BgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    ' Is the Background Worker do some work?
    If My_BgWorker.IsBusy Then
        'If it supports cancellation, Cancel It
        If My_BgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
            ' Tell the Background Worker to stop working.
            My_BgWorker.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End If
    ' Enable to Start Button
    Me.btnExit.Enabled = True
    ' Disable to Stop Button
    Me.btnExit.Enabled = False
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

End Class

Anyone can help me, whats the best way to show MDIParent (the main form) in sub RunWorkerCompleted, after splash form finish to loading. 
In my code above, MDIParent1 cannot show correctly because after show, application closed/terminated.

Comment: In the past, I've loaded the splash form from my MDIParent and set the MDIParent visibility to false until everything was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In Project --> Properties, set your MDIParent as the "Startup form", and set your Splash Form as the "Splash form".

Now place all of your initialization checks in the Load() event of the MDIParent **without** using any Threading or BackgroundWorkers.    The Splash Form will display for as long as the Load() event takes to complete, then will close automatically.

To update the splash from your MDIParent, cast [My.Application.SplashScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t310742(v=vs.90).aspx) to your Splash Form type, and use delegates/Invoke() as you're already doing.

Here's a silly example:

```
Public Class frmMdiParent

    Private Sub frmMdiParent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' initialization...
        Dim splash As frmSplash = DirectCast(My.Application.SplashScreen, frmSplash)
        Dim numberSteps As Integer = 10
        For i As Integer = 1 To numberSteps
            splash.Invoke(Sub()
                              splash.Label1.Text = "Step " & i & " of " & numberSteps
                          End Sub)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next

        ' some other stuff...
        Dim child As New Form
        child.MdiParent = Me
        child.Text = "Some MdiChild..."
        child.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: your respond give me some clue and another way to add splash screen in project. In my question, whats different between Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize and Private Sub MyApplication_Startup in applicationevents.vb? and which the best way to put Initializing process before run in main form, in sub of Protected Overrides Function OnInitialize or Private Sub MyApplication_Startup?

Comment: I believe OnInitialize() fires before the Startup() event...you could throw in some debug messages or breakpoints to verify that.  The "best way" is subjective.  These two methods occur BEFORE any form is displayed (the splash and the main form).  You can also **cancel** the application and prevent any forms from appearing at all when you use code in Startup().  A disadvantage to using Startup() is there is no place to give feedback/progress to the user.  Whether this is a good thing or not just depends on your particular scenario...